# ASP.NET Web API: "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST', PUT, DELETE." in Postman

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to create a simple `ASP.NET` `Web API` that gets, posts, puts, and deletes entries `(pharmacyName, pharmacyAddress, pharmacyCategory)` into a `MySQL` database. Both my `"GET"` functions successfully execute, but when I test `POST, PUT`, or `DELETE` functionality in `Postman`, I receive the following error:

> "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method
>   'POST'."

I have searched the forums and the Web for a solution, but I have been unable to find an answer pertaining to my case. I am a beginner, so please forgive me if I overlooked something or used improper/confusing terminology or coding structure.

The request URL I am using in Postman is `"localhost:59353/api/values/`. Below are blocks of code from my `ValuesController.cs, RouteConfig.cs, and WebAPIConfig.cs` files:

ValuesController.cs POST method:

```
// POST api/values
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]string pharmacyName, string pharmacyAddress, string pharmacyCategory)
{

    MySqlConnection conn = WebApiConfig.conn();

    MySqlCommand query = conn.CreateCommand();

    query.CommandText = "INSERT INTO locations (pharmacyName, pharmacyAddress, pharmacyCategory) VALUES (@pharmacyName, @pharmacyAddress, @pharmacyCategory)";

    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pharmacyName", pharmacyName);
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pharmacyAddress", pharmacyAddress);
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pharmacyCategory", pharmacyCategory);


    var results = new List<results>();

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
    }

    catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
    {
        results.Add(new results(null, null, null, ex.ToString()));
    }

    MySqlDataReader fetch_query = query.ExecuteReader();

    while (fetch_query.Read())
    {
        results.Add(new results(fetch_query["pharmacyName"].ToString(), fetch_query["pharmacyAddress"].ToString(), fetch_query["pharmacyCategory"].ToString(), null));
    }


}
```

RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

WebAPIConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static MySqlConnection conn()
        {
            string conn_string = "server=localhost;port=3306;database=map;username=root;password=123456";

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string);

            return conn;
        }
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add also how you send your request from Postman?

Comment: I am changing the dropdown to "POST" and using Request URL "localhost:59353/api/values/.'

Answer (score 1):

Simple types like **string,int,float** etc are to be fetched from query string in .Net framework where as complex types always fetched from body.

#### Solution-1

In this case .Net Framework is expecting string **pharmacyAddress** and **pharmacyCategory** from query parameters and you can call your API like this without making any change to your server side code.

*Note:Also you don't need to define key of the parameter (in http request) which is being defined as `[From Body]`. As total of one simple type can be passed using `[FromBody]` attribute* which you can see below like this `=pharmacyNameContent`

```
POST /api/values?pharmacyAddress=myaddress&pharmacyCategory=mycategory HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:59353
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
=pharmacyNameContent
```

#### Solution-2

Or you can call your API by putting all your params in complex model and pass params through body instead of query parameters like this

**Complex Type Model**

```
public class PharmacyModel
    {
        public string PharmacyName { get; set; }
        public string PharmacyAddress { get; set; }
        public string PharmacyCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

**API code**

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public void Post(PharmacyModel pharamcyModel)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = WebApiConfig.conn();
    MySqlCommand query = conn.CreateCommand();

    //Access your propeties like this
    query.CommandText = "INSERT INTO locations (pharamcyModel.PharmacyName, pharamcyModel.PharmacyAddress, pharamcyModel.PharmacyCategory) VALUES (@pharmacyName, @pharmacyAddress, @pharmacyCategory)";

  //rest of the coding
}
```

And now you can consume your API by passing paramters through body like this

```
POST /api/values? HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:59353
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

pharmacyAddress=myaddress&pharmacyCategory=mycategory&pharmacyName=nameOfPharmacy
```

It will surely gonna work as its already implemented and tested from my end